# how to select an image in a list of image in wrappannel wpf

Tags: wpf, c#-3.0

I add images from the filedialog in my programm. i want to kow how i can give them attribute like select_event on click for example to remove one.
 Thanks in advance

XAML Code .

```
               <Grid  DockPanel.Dock="Top"  Margin="5,5,5,5" Background="#FFA59A9A">

                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <WrapPanel Name="Picture_Holder" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal"/>

                    </ScrollViewer>

                </Grid>
```

C# code

```
        OpenFileDialog OpenFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        OpenFile.Multiselect = true;
        OpenFile.Title = "Select Picture(s)";
        OpenFile.Filter = "ALL supported Graphics| *.jpeg; *.jpg;*.png;";
        if (OpenFile.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            foreach(String file in OpenFile.FileNames)
            {
                Add_Image(file);
            }
        }



    private void Add_Image(string file)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Une image"+file);
        Image new_img = new Image();
        new_img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file));
        Thickness img_thickness = new Thickness();
        img_thickness.Bottom = 2;
        img_thickness.Left = 2;
        img_thickness.Right = 2;
        img_thickness.Top = 2;
        new_img.Margin = img_thickness;
        new_img.MaxWidth = new_img.MaxHeight = 105;
        Picture_Holder.Children.Add(new_img);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a ListBox like shown below, because it has built-in support for item selection. The WrapPanel would go into the `ItemsPanel` property of the ListBox.

```
<ListBox x:Name="imageListBox" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" MaxWidth="105" MaxHeight="105" Margin="2"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Then assign a collection of file path strings to its `ItemsSource` property:

```
imageListBox.ItemsSource = OpenFile.FileNames;
```

You can now get the file path of the selected image by the `SelectedItem` property of the ListBox.

In order to use BitmapImage items instead of strings - and thus get a BitmapImage as SelectedItem - write:

```
imageListBox.ItemsSource = OpenFile.FileNames
    .Select(path => new BitmapImage(new Uri(path)));
```

---

The next step would be to have a view model with a property that holds the image collection:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> Images { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>();

    private ImageSource selectedImage;

    public ImageSource SelectedImage
    {
        get { return selectedImage; }
        set
        {
            selectedImage = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedImage)));
        }
    }
}
```

You would assign an instance of the view model to the DataContext property of the MainWindow

```
DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

and bind to its properties in XAML:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImage}">
    ...
</ListBox>
```

To populate the Images collection in the view model:

```
var vm = (ViewModel)DataContext;
vm.Images.Clear();

foreach (var path in OpenFile.FileNames)
{
    vm.Images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(path)));
}
```

Remove the selected one by e.g.

```
vm.Images.Remove(vm.SelectedImage);
```

which could be executed in an `ICommand` in the view model.